# TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: mysql, laravel, string, session, offset

**In laravel I have created a session where I have stored a row of user table which include id, name and so on. I have created a condition where if the session exists then only access the ID stored in that table row via session.
And, when I run the code the session exists but when it comes to accessing the ID, it says "Cannot access offset of type string on string".**

***The following are the codes:-***

**Code where i have created a session:-**

```
  class UserController extends Controller
{
    function login(Request $req)
    {
        $user= User::where(["email"=>$req->email])->first();
        if(!$user || !Hash::check($req->password, $user->password))
        {
            return "username or password is not matched";
        }
        else{ 
            $req->session()->put("user", "$user");
            return redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```

**Code where m trying to access the ID via session:-**

```
if ($req->session()->has("user"))
         {
            $cart = new Cart;
      
            $cart->user_id = $req->session()->get('user')['id'];
            $cart->product_id = $req->product_id;

            $cart->save();

            return redirect("/");
        } 
        else
         {
            return redirect("/login");
        }
```

Comment: I guess index ```id``` not found, try to debuging first. Like this ```dd($req->session()->get('user'));``` to check the session user exists

Comment: Before you run `session()->put('user', $user);`, do a `dd($user)`. Is it a `string` or a `User` model instance? Your error suggests that it is not what you think it is. Also, for Models, `->` object access is preferred: `session()->get('user')->id;`

Comment: @TimLewis its a string

Comment: There's your issue. `'string'['id']` doesn't work  You need to save a User model instance to session.

Comment: @TimLewis but I want to save one particular user's data only in session, so if i assign Model's instance to session then it will assign entire user table data then how can i  access that particular user's data row?

Comment: Save a single instace in the session, not every row... A single User instance is **not** the entire `users` table. Like `$user = User::find($userId)`, then `session()->put($user)`. You're not showing how you define `$user` in your question, consider [updating your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69560099/edit) with that information.

Comment: @TimLewis I have now included the entire code where I have defined $user. Would you please check

Comment: @TimLewis and i guess i have done something similar to what you said but not sure. Will  you please guide

Comment: I think the issue might be that you're wrapping the `$user` variable in `""`: `$req->session()->put("user", "$user");`. Does it work with `$req->session()->put('user', $user);`? `->first()` does return a single User model instance, so that part of the code is correct.

Comment: On another note, using Laravel's authentication, when you login, the authenticated User is available via `auth()->user()`, so manually saving them to `session()` seems redundant here  (i.e. it looks like you're trying to "recreate the wheel" as they say)

Comment: @TimLewis  $req->session()->put('user', $user);  not working

Comment: I don't know what to tell you; it works just fine for me: `session()->put('user', $user);`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLBoZ.png and `session()->get('user')['id'];`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMlvC.png